# My xslt is not showing the line breaks within a paragarph

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, line-breaks

My xslt is not displaying the middle line breaks.

**Input:**
This data is fetched from sql server column

```
 hello

 www.xyz.com

 hello
 line 1
```

**Template:**

```
<xsl:template name="replace">
<xsl:param name="TFooter" />
<xsl:param name="search-string" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'" />
<xsl:if test="contains($TFooter, $search-string)">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($TFooter, $search-string)" />
  <fo:block />
</xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="contains($TFooter, $search-string)">
  <!-- recursive call -->
  <xsl:call-template name="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="TFooter" select="substring-after($TFooter, $search-string)" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

We can call the template from here:

```
<fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="1mm" padding-left="0.5cm">
                  <fo:block disable-output-escaping="yes" font-size="10pt" text-align="left">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                      <xsl:with-param name="TFooter" select="FooterText" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
```

Current output:

```
hello
www.xyz.com
hello
line 1
```

Desired Output:

```
hello

www.xyz.com

hello
line 1
```

How can i achieve the middle line breaks using xslt 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `<xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>` is missing in template `replace`

If your **input** (the data fetched from sql server column) is in XML as below: (for an example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FooterText>
     hello

     www.xyz.com

     hello
     line 1
</FooterText>
```

Then the code can be rewritten as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="1mm" padding-left="0.5cm">
            <fo:block disable-output-escaping="yes" font-size="10pt"
                text-align="left">
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="TFooter" select="FooterText" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="TFooter" />
    <xsl:param name="search-string" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'" />
    <xsl:if test="contains($TFooter, $search-string)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($TFooter, $search-string)" />
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <fo:block />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($TFooter, $search-string)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="TFooter"
                select="substring-after($TFooter, $search-string)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8X/9